# jQuery Drag and Drop tolerance

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

Is there any trick to edit `tolerance` in the `.droppable()` function?
I know there are the options like:

> "**fit**": Draggable overlaps the droppable entirely.
>
> "**intersect**": Draggable overlaps the droppable at least 50% in both directions.
>
> "**pointer**": Mouse pointer overlaps the droppable.
>
> "**touch**": Draggable overlaps the droppable any amount.

```js
 $('.grid').droppable( {
        hoverClass: "drop-hover",
        tolerance: 'intersect', /*how can I edit this?*/
        drop: function(event,ui){           
            $(this).append(ui.draggable.css({top: 0,left:0,zIndex:0,opacity:1}, 500));      
        },
        over: function previewMoveChange( event, ui ) {'do sth.'});
};
```

I want to have sth. like **if(DragableDiv == 35% over DropableDiv)**

Comment: There is no logic built in to the plugin to do what you require. You would need to extend the `droppable` method to add this feature. Is the difference between the 50% coverage of `intersect` and the 35% you require that imperative?

Comment: I am building an editable Dashboard. The Problem is, I have a Gridsystem with dragable div's, with the _bootstrap_ Gridsize (20px space each square). I show in the `over: function()` where the other Sqares will move to, and with the tolerance of 50% sometimes u activate the wrong preview just by moving past. So my why of thinking was, if i could reduce the sensivity of my `over: Function()` it won't bug that much^^ -